# Building a concrete basement one year and the structure on top the following one

Tags: concrete, basement, construction

Suppose you pour a concrete basement (consisting of a foundation at the bottom, four walls, concrete slab over the four walls) one summer, then return the following summer to build a bungalow on top.

The basement is finished and livable for the nine months of Fall/Winter/Spring.

You know with certainty that it will snow during winter. What do you do to your finished basement to make sure your time and money is not burnt?

Comment: @isherwood I've been on SE sites since 2011, and you and I had many (friendly) interactions on dyi.SE—but then I had to use a separate identity. When posting two similar questions, I repeatedly got asked to put them as two sides of the same coin in the same post and to avoid flooding the site. Darned if you do; darned if you don't. In this particular case, solving one issue without the other is useless.

Comment: These are not at all related questions. Load bearing and corrosion protection are entirely different issues. The fact that they involve the same structure isn't relevant. You might as well group how to change your car's oil and its top speed.

Comment: I would seal the floor in the basement - it will reduce dampness and dust.

Comment: @isherwood How's that? It's one question only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2-4 feet of snow is an utterly insignificant load to a concrete basement suitable to build a house on.

The reinforcement is protected from corrosion by being correctly placed within the pour so it has adequate concrete cover.

You might still want a temporary roof to shed water so that the unheated basement does not fill with water and get damaged by freeze expansion of trapped water into ice.

**Edit following various changes to the question, and comments:** There are very few places on the planet where a 1000kg/m**2 or 204 lbs/ft**2 snow load is realistic. You'll need to know the actual design snow load for the location to build the roof in a year anyway, so find it out now. 2-4 feet (600-1200mm) of snow does not weigh anything like that much, and unless someone is using a front loader to dump a parking lot worth of snow on your foundation, that's an utterly unrealistic scenario.

If the building foundation is not mere habitable, but inhabited, you can shovel the snow off, or poorly insulate the floor-as-roof and waste energy melting it off for a year. But most likely you won't have to worry about it at all, as the design floor loading will easily carry the snow load.

It's moderately common in the snowy area I inhabit for people to build a foundation and first floor deck, then use what will eventually be framing lumber for the upper story or stories to construct a low-slope temporary roof on the floor deck. The primary reason to slope that is to remove standing water, nothing so steep as to shed snow is required. The basement would not be *habitable* without providing some sort of roof at the floor deck, until the permanent roof is constructed above.

Comment: Nice coverage of not just the two points asked, but also a third. Thanks. About being insignificant, yes, a foot of loose snow is nothing. I'm more concerned about repeated cycles of thaw-compaction-refreezing that would, at the limit, make one meter of "snow" become one metric ton per square meter. I suppose a temporary (slanted) roof would solve both issues.

Comment: @Sam   Imagine if there is a possibility of snow collecting on the floor, there is also a good chance of rain collecting.  A sealed up hole could collect quite a bit of water that will freeze.  Imagine the time between foundation being finish and first snow will be a month or two

Comment: @Sam "repeated cycles of thaw-compaction-refreezing" Ah, but melting snow and refreezing it as ice does not change its weight. It only changes the density. So it's the same load, and still no need to worry about it.

Comment: @MTA right... in a way it's no different than the worry about shingles being pulled by a layer of ice if the weather builds up a big enough layer, except that if the surface is flat the risk is that much higher of snow collecting as ice.

Comment: @crip659 In hindsight that's a better question to have asked: What do I need to do if I build a foundation one year and the structure in a following year. What do you think, Ecnerwal (I believe you get notified of third-party comments under your answer): is a sequel question a good idea, or updating this question after your answer, or...?

Comment: @Sam  2 to 4 feet of snow is only about 0.2 to 0.4 feet of water(if contained).  Think snow is ~10% water.  With a flat surface and no walls, most melted water would be gone/flow off.

Comment: I don't see how snow load would be a problem for the concrete basement mentioned in this specific question, but a general comment on *"realistic loads"* (of any kind): safety margins are quite large because we don't want a lot of our buildings to collapse during extreme situations, and climate *is* changing (not just a higher average temperature, but also more heat and cold extremes) :)

Comment: @crig659 Are you asking me a question or answering my question? ;-) Water is a surprisingly versatile substance, and its behavior goes far beyond the chemistry and physics labs. If the temperature goes up just enough, without crossing into above-freezing, snow tends to compact rather than outright melt. It of course also sublimates, but if the temperature goes up and down fast enough, and if enough snow falls, one can end up with substantial snow/slush/ice cover, especially on a flat surface.

Answer (score 1):

For the edited question.

I would probably wait a year and do both the same year.

It at least saves the time and money to pump out the water and maybe cleaning the concrete floor and walls.

If water collects it will freeze.  I think most of the expansion when water freezes will be up, but if there is any sideways expansion, it could destroy/move the walls.

There could also be a liability question of animals/people/kids falling in a hole with/out water in it.

Second edit of question added in a ceiling/roof, while this answer was for just the four walls open to nature without a top.

Comment: Wait, it sounds like we were talking about two different kinds of basement. Mea culpa. I didn't define it carefully. By concrete basement I mean that all six sides (ground, four walls, basement ceiling aka bungalow floor) are poured concrete.

Comment: @Sam  That is much different then, since the basement itself will be sealed from getting wet/flooded.  You only need to worry about the ceiling holding the snow load, which local building department/inspector should know before building.  Being flat the floor/roof will have different needs compared to a slant roof.